# Upload app on iTunes connect

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, itunes, profiles

Well I am trying to upload a application on iTunes but I get this error message ""Your account already has a valid iOS Distribution certificate"". As I understand I need to remove the certificate from the App. How can I do that ? if I am wrong, any idea how can i upload my app on iTunes?

Comment: How are you trying to submit it? Via Xcode or application loader?

Comment: vIA Xcode, actually I try to validate it in order to 'update' my app. THANKS

Comment: So the steps are archive > organiser > Submit... > Choose development team > Submit ? How far along are you getting in the process, please provide as much information as possible.

Comment: Well i done those steps many times but still it does not working !! @Gary Riches

Comment: That is not providing as much information as possible. Xcode version? Which step is it failing on? Have you successfully submitted an app on this machine before?

Comment: Yes I did, What kind of information I need to provide?. The Validation Step is failling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand you're problem. You must be validating instead of submitting. In order to upload your app to iTunes Connect, in organizer, you must "Submit" your archive. This will upload it into iTunes connect.